# Can you gift downloadable content?

Tags: ps3

I'm looking to sell my ps3 and games separately. Can I give away any DLC with the relevant games?

Comment: are you talking about games and/or dlc bought in the psn?

Comment: DLC for example I have rocksmith disk but also a lot of purchased song packs.

Comment: DLC's and games bought in the PSN are bound to your account so it's not possible to gift anything out of it.

Comment: ok another question would it work to pull the file off the ps3 and transfer it by usb?

Comment: What you mean by "the file"? It's not possible to copy Game-Files if you mean that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why, but the PSN store/Sony has no such feature.

So you can not gift anything from your Ps3. All the games/DLC's you have downloaded will be linked with your PSN account.

Here you have some forum, were they talk about it:

- [PlayStation Forum - Can you gift games from PS Store?](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-General/Can-you-gift-games-from-PS-Store/td-p/43081655)
- [PlayStation Forum - Can you "gift" DLC?](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PSN-Games-General/Can-you-quot-gift-quot-DLC/td-p/14938449)
- [GameFAQ - Has sony allowed us gift psn games yet?](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/927750-playstation-3/65296074)

Answer (score 0):

All purchases from the PSN store are attached to your account and can not be transferred in any way, much like other digital distribution systems like Steam, Origin or XBL. None of them allow you to transfer content, that's pretty normal.